# async task testing

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, rhino-mocks

I just started using Rhino Mocks that test my async methods within the code. But while normally the code works just perfect but while mocking tests with Rhino Mocks there are some weird `async` problems.

Let's say I want to test the following code which calls multiple `numberGenerators` that all will run at the same time and wait till they are all done:

```
public async Task MyTask()
{
    List<Task<List<int>>> numberTasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>();

    foreach (var numberGenerator in numberGenerators)
    {
        // GetNumbers is an 'async Task<List<int>>'
        // As you can see I don't use 'await' so it should just add it and go on.
        numberTasks.Add(numberGenerator.GetNumbers()); 
    }

    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(numberTasks);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log exception if something happens at 'GetNumbers' (like time-out or whatever)
    }

    var numbers = new List<int>();
    numbers.AddRange(numberTasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).SelectMany(task => task.Result));

    // Do something with the numbers
}
```

Is tested with:

```
numberGenerator.Expect(x => x.GetNumbers())
    .WhenCalled(x => Thread.Sleep(10000))
    .Return(Task.FromResult(numbers));
```

I use two of the generators on 'mocked' in the code above. Now if I run the code with 'non-mocked' objects `numberTasks.Add` just adds the Task and moves on. But when I mock it with the `WhenCalled sleep` it waites for 10 seconds before going to the next one in the foreach loop.

How can I change my mock that it acts like a normal `async Task` that takes 10 seconds to complete?

Bonus question: Can want to be able to do the same with `.Throw()` so I can wait 10 seconds before throwing an Exception.

**Update:**
Although I thought the following would fix the problem:

```
numberGenerator.Expect(x => x.GetNumbers())
    .Return(Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => numbers));
```

This doesn't seem to be the case. The Task.Delay starts counting down at the moment this `mock` is created. So if I create this mock, wait 10 seconds and then run the test it will be done in 0 seconds.

So my question remains, how can I test an async method with a `delay` before returning the result.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Actually the original topic was okay, http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."

Comment: @Tseng actually, even with tags, the original title was not okay - in no way ... It was just a catenation of some terms, and missing a clear question/title whatsoever. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. *Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An async method runs synchronously until an `await` is reached. That means if you wait before returning a task in the mocked operation this wait will be synchronous. What you want to do is return a task immediately that completes after some time.

You can do that with `Task.Delay`:

```
numberGenerator.Expect(x => x.GetNumbers()).
        Return(Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t => numbers));
```

`Task.ContinueWith` is used to add the actual return value after the delay is completed.

If you would like to throw an exception instead of returning a value, that too can be done inside the continuation.

Since `Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t => numbers)` is evaluated when you create the mock, each call would return the same task (which will be completed 10 seconds after the mock was created).

If you need to create a new task each time you need to pass a delegate. `Return` doesn't accept a delegate so you need to use `WhenCalled`:

```
numberGenerator.Expect(x => x.GetNumbers()).
        WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => numbers));
```

Now, while `WhenCalled` is used to set the return value using `Return` is still required [in order to determine the type of the return result](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2011/07/28/using-rhino-mocks-whencalled-remember-to-return/). It doesn't matter what value it gets as the return value will still be set by `WhenCalled`:

```
numberGenerator.Expect(x => x.GetNumbers()).
    WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => numbers)).
    Return(Task.FromResult(new List<int>()));
```

Comment: One weird thing, if I add this code you wrote and instead of adding tasks in the foreach I await them in the foreach. It is still done in about 10 seconds. It looks like it just skips to the next in the foreach eventhough there is an await.

Comment: @Julian I don't think so. The task you create before passing to `Return` is the same task that will complete in 10 seconds. When the first item returns it it will wait for 10 seconds but the second will move on because the task already completed. If you want to return a new task each time you need a `Return` that accepts a delegate or something similar.

Comment: after testing alot the problem doesn't seem to be fixed because the `Task.Delay` starts running at the moment the `mock` is made.

Comment: @Julian of course. That's what my previous comment states. If you want to generate the task each time you need to pass in a delegate which will produce a new task each time. `Return` doesn't support that AFAIK but `WhenCalled` does: `WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => numbers))`

Comment: Ah sorry I completely misunderstood your comment than. If I only specify the `ReturnValue` in `WhenCalled` it tells me it doesn't have any return value. So it's working now with: `WhenCalled(mi => mi.ReturnValue = Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(x => numbers)).Returns(Task.FromResult(numbers));` Looks weird to me though but gives the right results. Thanks! (could you update your answer so I can accept it with this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I haven't worked with rhino mock, so I don't know if it supports async Method calls.

But `Thread.Sleep(10000)` is a synchronous code. If you want await in asynchronously you have to use `Task.Delay(10000)`.

Or alternatively use `Task.Run( () => Thread.Sleep(10000) )` though, `Task.Delay(10000)` is preferred way and best practice.